# Me sale este error al hacer login en php con MVC

Tags: php, mvc, login, undefined

Estoy haciendo el login de usuarios con php con un modelo vista controlador y al salir la pantalla de prueba de login ok o no ok me salen estos dos errores:

Warning: Use of undefined constant email - assumed 'email' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebBurger\lib\model\DB\UsuarioDB.php on line 47

Warning: Use of undefined constant contrasena - assumed 'contrasena' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebBurger\lib\model\DB\UsuarioDB.php on line 47

Concretamente hacen referencia a "email" y "contrasena" de la línea **if($usuario == $r[email] && $pwd == $r[contrasena])** del fichero **UsuarioDB.php** y he estado mirando y no sé que puede fallar, ya que el login lo hace correctamente y sale el mensaje de usuario logueado. Si me podéis ayudar. Muchas gracias!

controller/UsuarioController.php

```html
<?php 

require_once(__DIR__.'/../model/DB/UsuarioDB.php');

class UsuarioController{

public function login($u, $p){
        $db = new UsuarioDB();
        if($db->login($u, $p)){
            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $u;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    }
```

UsuarioDB.php

```html
<?php 

require_once(__DIR__.'/../Usuario.php');

class UsuarioDB{
    
    private $conexion;
    
    public function login($usuario, $password){
        $this->conectar();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$usuario'";
        $stm = $this->conexion->prepare($sql);
        $stm->execute();
        $result = $stm->get_result();
        
        $r = $result->fetch_assoc();
        
        $salt = md5('Sunrise');
        $contra = $salt.$password;
        $pwd = md5($contra);
        
        if($usuario == $r[email] && $pwd == $r[contrasena]){ 
        //Login OK
        return true;
        } else {
            //Login NO OK
            return false;
        }
    }
   }
```

form-login

```html
<form action="../public/forms/login.php" method="post">
       <dl>
      <dt><label for="email">EMAIL</label></dt>
      <dd><input type="text" id="uemail" name="uemail" /></dd>
      <dt><label for="contrasena">CONTRASEÑA</label></dt>
      <dd><input type="password" id="ucontra" name="ucontra" /></dd>
      <dd><input type="submit" name="ulogin" value="ENTRAR" /></dd>
      </dl>
</form>
```

/forms/login.php

```html
<?php

require_once(__DIR__.'/../../lib/controller/UsuarioController.php');

session_start();

$usuario = $_POST['uemail'];
$contra = $_POST['ucontra'];

$cnt = new UsuarioController();
$login = $cnt->login($usuario, $contra);

?><html>

<head>
    <title>Lista de frases</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php include(__DIR__.'/../../lib/inc/header.php'); ?>
    
      <?php if($login){ ?>Usuario logueado
      <a href="../index.php">Volver a la página principal</a>
      <?php }else{ ?> Usuario no logueado <a href="../index.php">Volver a la página principal</a> <?php } ?>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente cuando usas una variable sin `$` PHP lo asume como constante, en este caso `r[email]` y `r[contrasena]` ambas están como constantes.

Para solucionarlo, simplemente enciérralas entre comillas así sabrá que es el elemento llamada `'email'` y no buscará el valor de alguna constante llamada `email`

En resumen cambia esto.

```
if($usuario == $r[email] && $pwd == $r[contrasena]){
```

por esto

```
if($usuario == $r['email'] && $pwd == $r['contrasena']){
```